# Expected Value and Variance of Moving a Token on a Checkerboard Based on a Die Roll.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation, variance

> A fair four-sided die has its sides labeled U, D, L, and R, respectively. A token is placed at (0, 0) on the Cartesian plane and the die is then rolled repeatedly. After each roll, the token is moved as follows:
>
> ### Token Moves
>
> U (a, b) → (a, b + 1)
>
> D (a, b) → (a, b − 1)
>
> L (a, b) → (a + 1, b)
>
> R (a, b) → (a − 1, b)
>
> Let the random variable Yn be the taxicab distance. 
>   Taxicab distance is calculated by |a|+|b|.
>
> What is the expected value of Yn and why?
>
> What is the variance of Yn and why?

## What I know so far:

After using a program that I made and tracking the sample space of n=1, n=2, n=3 and n=4 I managed to determine an equation that seems to generate the correct expected value 100% of the time.

E(Yn)=E(Y(n-1))*(2n-1)/(2n-2)

I don't know how I'd go about proving this equation and I lack a conceptual understanding of why it works. I need help with finding why this relation works.

Comment: If what is causing you problems is the taxicab metric, then look it up to get some visual aid - it is quite a simple concept once you see it. This metric is useful in your problem because the token can only move in steps of size 1 in either direction (but cannot move at some other angle to the axes). Also, do you know the definition of expected value and variance? If so, have you tried using those definitions? If you have, please include that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value is to be $0$; if it was not, then then die must be biased toward a particular direction(s).

If each roll is treated as a new instance of a random variable, the variance of each roll with be exactly $1$. For example, with just one roll, you are guaranteed to be one square from the origin. If the new location of the token is set as a new origin, the variance of the next roll must also be $1$, and so on...

One of the most important rules of statistics says that variances of random variables are always additive; regardless of whether you are adding or subtracting the output values of the random variables. Thus, the variance in the question you are asking will simply be equal to the number of rolls performed.

Comment: Okay so here's my issue with this question. I actually wrote a program in C# to help me visualize this question a bit better. Intuitively it makes sense that the expected value is 0 but when I tried my small simulation of this problem the average I got was around 0.34 which is making me somewhat unsure. As for the expected variance I hadn't quite thought of it that way. My expected variance is simply V(Yn)=n?

Comment: Upon trying out my program again I realize I simply wasn't using averaging enough trials to get close to zero. Upon running the program with 100,000,000 trials and getting their average the number becomes infinitesimally small.

Comment: That's good. It's also possible there is an underlying bias in the pseudo-RNG; although I imagine C# is good with that.

Comment: I'm going to elaborate a bit more on what I'm still struggling with in this question. This question is part of a review packet for my university probability course. The question is out of ten with 5 marks for explaining why the expected value is 0 and 5 marks on what the expected variance is. I don't really know how I can elaborate on this question to the point where I'd get the 5 marks for each.

Comment: I hope I'm not too late, but if you still need some clarification, it might do good to ask this question on Stats Stack Exchange, regarding the variance part.

Comment: I can't really find the stats stack exchange. I looked through the drop down I don't really see it. Could you like me to it? (Nevermind I found it. It's the cross-validated stack exchange)

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/